# Atmega168 and ENC28j60 - Unable to communicate

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, ethernet, enc28j60

I would like to make a web server from an AVR uC. I use Atmega168 with the ENC28J60 ethernet module. I have connected the module with my Atmega using SPI. 
I have a problem, because the communication does not work. The green LED on the ENC module is solid green, and the yellow is flashing when I try to ping the device... Unfortunately I get the "Destination host unreachable message"

I am using the diagram and software provided in the tutorial from tuxgraphics.com 
http://tuxgraphics.org/electronics/200606/article06061.shtml

I tried to connect everything as it is here. I didn't connect the IO port. Just the LED to the Atmegas' PB1 (pin15);

The difference is, that I use the 5V to 3.3V converter to supply ENC28J60 with power. The input pins are 5V tolerant so I didn't use the 3.3V for the input pins. I supply to board with the 5V from the usbasp programmer.
I've noticed that sometimes the green LED flashes, but then I remove the power and connect it again it is solid green.

Do I need to change the Atmega from the 1MHZ?
I tried to use the external crystal oscillator from ENC module. I have set the low fuse to 0x60 (that info was in ReadMe file from Tuxgraphics)but I dont know if it worked... When i use AVRdude I get the following output:

```
avrdude -p m168 -c usbasp -v -q
Output:

    avrdude: Version 5.10, compiled on Jan 19 2010 at 10:45:23
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\WinAVR-20100110\bin\avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : lpt1
         Using Programmer              : usbasp
         AVR Part                      : ATMEGA168
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65     5     4    0 no        512    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     16384  128    128  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : usbasp
         Description     : USBasp, http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/

avrdude: auto set sck period (because given equals null)
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9406
avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as 60
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as DF
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as 1

avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as 60
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as DF
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as 1
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I am concerned about the: "avrdude: auto set sck period (because given equals null)"

Here are the photos of my circuit:

[image: Circuit]

And one more thing about the connection - I have an unamanaged switch. I use straight cables. So the topology is: Laptop > Switch > ENC28J60. When I run Wireshark I do not see any traffic coming from 192.16.0.2 (address of my ENC)
My computer is 192.168.0.100;

Regards!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually circuit worked for a while. I think that everything is OK but there's some instability....